# Old Users App Store Account is still active on my computer

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I just picked up a used Mac for a great price (I might add but doesn't have much to do with my question); and the old users App Store Account is still linked to him, even though I have everything else going with my iCloud account and or Apple password.  How do I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

Open the App Store app and go to Store → Sign Out.